# Cannot read "id" of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to acces my eventhandler which has an parameter Id, but i get this error. I have tried to rewrite the code but i get the same error. I get i am doing something wrong when im trying to props the id,  but im not sure.

```
import React from "react";

function Props(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={props.todoItem.completed}
          onChange={() => props.handleChange(props.item.id)}
        />
      </h3>
      <p> {props.todoItem.text} </p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Props;
```

```
import React from "react";

import Props from "./props";
import ToDoData from "../ToDoData";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      todos: ToDoData
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(id) {
    console.log("changed", id);
  }

  render() {
    //Her henter du data, hvor du bruger mapping med map()
    const ReturnToDo = this.state.todos.map(item => (
      <Props key={item.id} todoItem={item} handleChange={this.handleChange} />
    ));
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        {ReturnToDo}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are not passing a prop `item` to `Prop`. The closest is `todoItem`.

Comment: change your onChange={() => props.handleChange(props.todoItem.id)}

Answer (score 0):

Your props here is `tooItem` and you are accessing `item` in the child component.
`<Props key={item.id} todoItem={item} handleChange={this.handleChange} />`

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  checked={props.todoItem.completed}
  onChange={() => props.handleChange(props.item.id)} // here there is no item in props, its todoItem
 />
```

Comment: but the (item.id) has a key property that confused me because i had to set a key prop before it worked

Comment: @Dev_Jensen: You have to use `key` when rendering elements as arrays. Can you elaborate on what confused you?

Comment: @Dev_Jensen `key` property is in the parent Component, while iterating a list, we need to use a `key` property to maintain the uniqueness of iteration.

Comment: forget about key here, you are passing your array item in ( `<Props key={item.id} todoItem={item} handleChange={this.handleChange} />`  ) ``todoItem`` here, so you need to access that `props` key

Answer (score 0):

You should change the Props function to something like this since you are passing the item form parent as a todoItem prop for the child.

```
import React from "react";

function Props(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={props.todoItem.completed}
          onChange={() => props.handleChange(props.todoItem.id)}
        />
      </h3>
      <p> {props.todoItem.text} </p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Props;
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can use like this**

```
import React from "react";

function Props(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={props.todoItem.completed}
          onChange={() => props.handleChange(props.key)}
        />
      </h3>
      <p> {props.todoItem.text} </p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Props;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are passing `todoItem` to **Props** component and accessing `item` instead of `todoItem`.

Destructured way

```
function Props({todoItem, handleChange}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={todoItem.completed}
          onChange={() => handleChange(todoItem.id)}
        />
      </h3>
      <p> {todoItem.text} </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On onChange event you have used undefined props. Try this

```
import React from "react";

function Props(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={props.todoItem.completed}
          onChange={() => props.handleChange(props.todoItem.id)}
        />
      </h3>
      <p> {props.todoItem.text} </p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Props;
```